# Is there any way to configure spring mvc to assume a content-type?

Tags: java, json, spring, spring-mvc, content-type

I have a method to which I want to post some json data, that looks like this

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/m1", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public Object m1(@RequestBody Map<String, ?> body) {
    // do something
}
```

This works great when I set the `content-type` header to `application/json` when I post, but fails with an error if I don't (it cannot deserialize the post body into the map because it doesn't know how)

What would I have to configure in spring to make it use `application/json` as a default when no header is specified?

Comment: Why isn't the request header being supplied to start with? You're trying to contravene the HTTP/MIME protocol if you ignore it.

Comment: Although I posted an answer below... I would highly recommend you consider skaffman's approach if at all possible.

Comment: @aweigold, I +1'd your answer, but between you two, I'm convinced it's weird so I'm not going to actually implement it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The class that converts the JSON to your object is called an `HttpMessageConverter`.  I assume you are using the default Jackson one that comes with Spring.  You can write a custom [`MessageConverter`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/http/converter/AbstractHttpMessageConverter.html), that will always return true in it's supports method with your response object type and then just call the Jackson httpconverter in your readInternal and writeInternal methods.  If you do this however, be careful, as once it's registered in your requesthandler, it will be asked on all `@ResponseBody` and `@RequestBody` requests.